# Parcelable for object

Tags: android, model, parcelable

I want to ask how to send Parcelable for object?
This is my model

```
data class CheckoutResponseMdl(val items: ItemsCheckout) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(TODO("items")) {
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {

}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<CheckoutResponseMdl> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): CheckoutResponseMdl {
        return CheckoutResponseMdl(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<CheckoutResponseMdl?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}}
```

what I suppose to do at *TODO("items")* ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You need to write each property to `Parcel` and rebuild it by reading `Parcel` in constructor. have a look at [This](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/reducing-parcelable-boilerplate-code-using-kotlin-741c3124a49a).